# PostgreSQL procedure: insert returning created id

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have this procedure:

```sql
create procedure get_users(
  name text
) language plpgsql AS $$
begin
   insert into "user" (
    "id",
    "name"
  ) values (
    uuid_generate_v4(),
    name
  );
end;
$$;
```

I wonder if it is possible to return the created id without using a function. That's because I try to use functions for queries and procedures for commands to comply with CQRS as much as possible.

Here is a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a8670a6809dcd38d75ef0b76efb96acd

Answer (score 0):

```
create procedure get_users
(
  name text
) 
language plpgsql AS $$
begin
    
   insert into "user" 
   ("id", "name") values 
   (uuid_generate_v4(), name) 
   returning "id", "name" into p_id, p_name
  
end;
$$;
```

P.S. `p_id` and `p_name` are declare variables.

Comment: Hm, don't see it. Can't add the variables. May you put a fiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

```
create procedure get_users
(
  name text
) 
language plpgsql AS $$
declare
    p_id text;
    p_name text; 
begin
    
   insert into "user" 
   ("id", "name") values 
   (uuid_generate_v4(), name) 
   returning "id", "name" into p_id, p_name;
  
end;
$$;
```

I don't know your table structure and field types. For examples, I used `text` type for same (`p_id` and `p_name`) variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, provided you have Postgres v11 or higher. You can declare an `inout` parameter (in V14 just need `out` parameter). Your insert can then return the created id into that parameter. Perhaps (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=be8d2514626d6351adef1f9bdcbb21c4))

```
create or replace 
procedure establish_users(
    name_in text
 ,  inout user_id_ot uuid
 ) language plpgsql 
as $$
begin
   insert into "user" (name) 
   values (name_in)
   returning id into user_id_ot;
end;
$$;
```